# Our vlans can contact each other, we wan't them to not be able to

Tags: cisco, routing

We have 2 vlans

vlan 20 & vlan 30

they are both currently able to contact each other but we don't want them to be able to. We have 2 switches too, with these vlans on them.

They should not be able to contact each other on the same switch or going through another switch.

Would we have to set up an ACL to stop this or are there commnads we can use to set up such paramiters when we set up VLAN's

edit: trunking is enable on both switches

Comment: What manufacturer and model are the switches?  Could you add a diagram with their connectivity and/or the configuration on the switches?  Check out the [NE Question Checklist](http://tinyurl.com/ne-checklist) for more hints on how to help us help you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

A VLAN is a layer-2 concept. If there's IP (layer-3) connectivity between them, then there's a router somewhere routing between VLANs. It will naturally *route* between them until you actively prevent it, most often with an ACL.

(a more complex setup could be done with VRF.)

Comment: Thanks for that, turns out we didn't need an ACL after all, the VLANs were supposed to be able to ping each other.